# Output is not displying correctly in file operation

Tags: c, file

Can anybody explain what is the mistake in this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  FILE *f1;
  char c;
  f1 = fopen("INPUT", "w");
  while((c=getchar()) != '/')
    putc(c, f1);
  fclose(f1);
  f1 = fopen ("INPUT", "r");
  while ((c = getc(f1) != EOF))
    printf("%c", c); 
  fclose(f1);
}
```

The output is coming in undetectable font. I tried in windows also. But the same result.

Comment: Please provide your test input which makes ""undetectable font."

Comment: should be int c, not char c

Comment: @timrau for any input, like `stackoverflow/`

Comment: @AliVeli No. Should be `putc((unsigned char) c, f1);`. c should be a `char` as it's later used (incorrectly) in conjunction with printf's %c format specifier. *edit*: Ooops. Indeed, it should be, due to `c=getchar()`

Comment: @modifiablelvalue `c` must be an `int`, since getc() returns the character as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`. If you use a `char` instead, you can't distinguish between `EOF` and a character with the same value as `EOF`.

Comment: @NikosC. Note the *edit*, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`. putc() takes an `int` and, more importantly, getc() reads the next character from the stream and returns it as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`, or EOF on end of file or error. If you store it into a `char` instead, `EOF` gets lost since `char` is too narrow and can't represent that.  getc()

Second, this is wrong:

```
while ((c = getc(f1) != EOF))
```

what you want here is:

```
while ((c = getc(f1)) != EOF)
```

You've misplaced a parenthesis.

Remember that you need to alter your printf() call since `c` is now an `int`:

```
printf("%c", (char)c);
```

You need the explicit cast because printf() is a variadic function and therefore the compiler performs no automatic type conversion. You need to cast manually with variadic functions.

Comment: @noufal You also need an `int` for `c`, not a `char`.

Comment: @noufal It's working for the data you have in your file. If a character in the file happens to have the same value as `EOF` and you read that character, then your code will think that it reached `EOF`. This is the reason why getc() returns `int` and not `char`. You have to store the result of getc() in an `int`, otherwise you can't reliably check for `EOF`.

Comment: I have one doubt, how could I enter `EOF` through Linux terminal?

Comment: @noufal EOF is generated in stdin with CTRL+D.