# Wrong data display on stdout: C File Operation

Tags: c, file-io

I wrote the following code:

```
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ftest.txt","r");
    char c, filestring[100];
    int i=0;
    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        filestring[i]=c;
    }
    printf("str is %s",filestring);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The file ftest.txt contains the words Hello World.

[image]

The output displayed is not correct, it is either some other font or some other encoding.

[image]

What is the reason for this? And how do I solve this problem?

At the same time, this code runs well (shows output on stdout in "English"):

```
 main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("ftest.txt","r");
        char c;
        while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

I need the first code to work, as I've to search in the text file. How to solve this?

The question is different from [Output is not displying correctly in file operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068811/output-is-not-displying-correctly-in-file-operation) as I'm able to "display" the correct output (as in second code), but I'm not able to write the contents of the file into a string.

Things I've tried:

1) Changing the mode in which the file is opened from "r" to "rb".

2) Changing the Notepad encoding to all available options: ANSI, UTF etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts of the answer:

- You never increment `i`.  This means you're just overwriting the same spot (the first space in the array) in the while loop.  That's why the first value of the junk is a 'd' (the last character of your input).
- The junk after the 'd' is because the array is never initialized, meaning that there is random junk already there that is never overwritten.

Another note: doing the first way would require manually adding a null byte `\0` to the end of the array (either by initializing the whole thing to `\0`s or just after the last character is read in.  This is so the string is read correctly by `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

... and there's also a third part that's wrong here:

getc() returns an `int`, you're assigning it to a `char` before comparing it with `EOF`, which is defined as -1. If it just so happens that getc returns character 255, it gets assigned to a char, a signed 8 bit value, which results in, in a manner of speaking (char)-1, which then gets signed-extended to -1.